# iOS: How to get and shuffle autoID data of users stored in childnode of firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently my data is structured like this in firebase:

[Image: Firebase structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPHX6.png)

I would like to grab a random autoID from the child node of the following tab and and present it as an option in a multiple choice format so that it looks like this (where option A,B,C,D are random but not the same):

[Image: How the app should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrZBV.png)

I'm new to swift and firebase so was wondering if you can help me with code that I can write to:

1. Enter the child node that shows who the user is following
2. Grab 4 random AutoID's from the list and present them as options A,B,C,D
3. Allowing the options to be UIButtons (or similar) so that I can send this screen to the user who was selected (as a notification)
4. Presenting the 4 users profile pictures (profileImageUrl) on the UIImageview so you can scroll through them (- this is an extra step but would also appreciate help on it)

I hope that makes sense,

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Comment: you will have to fetch them all at once and then get 4 random id's locally, there is no such function in firebase that gives random childs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would I go about fetching the users all at once and getting the 4 random id's locally? Wouldn't that be a problem if there were many users on the app or someone was following a lot of people?

Comment: yes, it will be a problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several questions within the question so let's address one.

How to select a random node from Firebase Realtime Database. Well, you don't do it with the Firebase API as Firebase doesn't offer that functionality. However, you can still do it.

First lets start with a typical users node

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Frank"
  uid_1
    name: "Leroy"
  uid_2
    name: "Henry"
  uid_3
    name: "Fred"
```

So if that's the users node, you can use it for this solution. However, many users node have a lot of other data stored in them - and to select a random node we don't care about that data. What we do is create another node that contains only the node keys - this will keep is pretty small, even if there are thousands of users

```
user_keys
   uid_0: true
   uid_1: true
   uid_2: true
   uid_3: true
```

Then, to select a random node, we load in all of the user keys using .value, iterate over them to load the keys into an array, then a Swift 4 random number generator to select some keys which we load into another array.

Then we iterate over that array to grab the actual user nodes from Firebase. We also don't want duplicates so as we select nodes from the array, we remove those nodes so they are not selected again. Here's a function to select 3 random nodes, retrieve the users data and print the users name.

```
func getThreeRandomNodesAndPrintUserName() {

    var myKeyArray = [String]()

    let ref = self.ref.child("user_keys")

    //retreives all nodes in the user_keys node
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in

        for child in snapshot.children { //build the array of keys
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            myKeyArray.append(key)
        }

        var randomKeyArray = [String]()

        for _ in 0...2 { //will iterate three times
            let count = myKeyArray.count //get the number of elements
            let randomInt = Int.random(in: 0..<count) //get a random index for the array
            let randomUserKey = myKeyArray[randomInt]
            randomKeyArray.append(randomUserKey)
            myKeyArray.remove(at: randomInt) //remove that object so it's not selected again
        }

        let numberOfKeys = randomKeyArray.count

        for i in 0..<numberOfKeys {
            let thisUserKey = randomKeyArray[i]
            let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(thisUserKey)
            userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as! String
                print(name)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

and then just a call to that function will print three random users names

```
self.getThreeRandomNodesAndPrintUserName()
```

and the output for first run

```
Fred
Frank
Henry
```

and then the second run

```
Henry
Leroy
Fred
```

etc

Comment: Thank you so much for the great explanation! Can you help me to see how I would then go about connecting each of the name outputs to a separate UIButton that i have linked from the storyboard? Really appreciate it :)

Comment: @edey We can take a look. However. This site functions best when questions are kept on a single topic. If this answer helped that part of your question, please accept it so it can help others. Also, post a separate question about working with the UI as that's not really related to Firebase. My guess is you can just set the title of each button (button 0, 1, 2, 3) to the 'name' var I included in my code above.

Comment: Okk i'll try that and will post a separate question if i have any problems - thanks again